# Multiple wars on Maven Embedded Tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have a project like that:

```
:: Parent POM Project
|_ Common Classes JAR Project
|_ WAR project 1
|_ WAR project 2
```

When i had only one WAR project, i used to run my tomcat as: tomcat:run and everything was fine.
Now, if i try that, it will only run the first WAR project. I want to deploy both at the same time, in the same embedded tomcat. One with context path: /war1 and the other with /war2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it isn't possible to deploy more than 1 WAR to the embedded tomcat.
That's too bad. You need to deploy your wars to a running tomcat server. This way you'll loose your hot code replacement features.